# multi color progress indicator

Tags: java, android, flutter

I want to make multi color progress bar with indicator in flutter, but I am not find any type of package.

[image]

Above image tell you, which I want design.
if any one have solution about problem tell me.

Comment: You can provide gradient background to the progressbar and if you don't find any other solution then you can go with the Stack and use container with gradient like this and then put the transparent progressbar above that. Ultimately if nothing works then you can use the image as well.